# Contar la cantidad del valores de las cartas de una mano en una baraja de 52 cartas

Tags: python

Necesito crear una función que me cuente la cantidad de veces que aparece cada valor de una mano de 5 cartas, sin importar ni el color ni el palo de estas. Para ello necesito crear una lista para contarlos. Por ejemplo, si en la mano tengo dos ases y tres "8" tendría que obtener esto : [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0]. Este sería mi código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor pon el código como texto. Lee [ask] para que sepas como preguntar y realiza el [tour] para que conozca el funcionamiento del sitio y obtengas tu primera medalla!

Comment: No describes la estrada de datos a la función. `valores_cartas` parece ser un **int** y `mano` no lo utilizas.

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que mano es un arreglo de enteros y valores_cartas es un entero.
En tu función debes volver a recorrer el arreglo para saber cuantas veces esta presente el valor.

Puedes usar la funcion count() sirve para contar las repeticiones de un valor en un arreglo o en un string.

```
def valor_mano(mano,valores_cartas):
    lista_numeros=[0]*valores_cartas
    for a in range(valores_cartas):
        #cuantas veces existe el valor a en la mano
        lista_numeros[a]=mano.count(a)
    return lista_numeros
```

Nota: es posible que valores_cartas sea una constante de ser así no sería necesario que lo recibas en la función puedes chequear eso.